# Prism - Do I really need to use a Prism region manager?

Tags: prism, region

I am building an application based on the WPF Application Framework (WAF). I think the framework has most of what I need but if there are any opportunities for making things easier for me then I'd like to take full advantage of them. I've been looking at Prism and I think my application might benefit from using some of the library features. Particularly after they release the new version.

My question concerns the Region Manager capabilities that PRISM brings me. Can someone tell me what are the killer features this offers that I can't just have through simple non-Prism coding.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is: 
if your app is simple - like 2-3 views and you do not want to benefit from the dynamic modules loading, IoC etc. you probably do not want to use PRISM, WAF, MEF. 
But if your app is big, you end up writing your own RegionManager. So why write a new one when you have already written for you ?